# Finding latitude and longitude using IPaddress

Tags: php, javascript, bing-maps

In my page I used the bingmap API to find the latitude and longitude of given address. Here is the script for that.

But What I need to do here is, how to get the zipcode by giving the IP address as input. Anybody can help me to achieve this functionality.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
                //check user has entered something first
                if ($("#txtAddress").val().length > 0) {
                    //send location query to bing maps REST api
                    $.getJSON('http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=' + $("#txtAddress").val() + '&key=mykey&jsonp=?', function (result) {
                        if (result.resourceSets[0].estimatedTotal > 0) {
                            var loc = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates;
                            $("#results").html('latitude:' + loc[0] + ', longitude:' + loc[1]);
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#results").html("sorry that address cannot be found");
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $("#results").html("please enter an address");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <label for="myaddress">Type an address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtAddress" />
    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Find Location" />
    <p id="results"></p>
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348614/how-to-determine-a-zip-code-and-city-from-an-ip-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$ip = "YOUR_IP_ADDRESS";

$_API = "API_KEY";
$_URL = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=$_API&ip=$ip&format=json";
```

**OutPut**

`{
    "statusCode" : "OK",
    "statusMessage" : "",
    "ipAddress" : "YOUR_IP_ADDRESS",
    "countryCode" : "IN",
    "countryName" : "INDIA",
    "regionName" : "GUJARAT",
    "cityName" : "AHMEDABAD",
    "zipCode" : "ZIPCODE",
    "latitude" : "23.0333",
    "longitude" : "72.6167",
    "timeZone" : "+05:30"
}`

`API_KEY` will be available at [**Ipinfodb**](http://www.ipinfodb.com).

Comment: How to get the API key. I am very new to this task. So can you please tell me how to get the api key

Comment: just register yourself there then they will guide you with some awesome example.

Comment: I am looking for an API that provides latitude and longitude accurate enough to locate the places 2 kilometers apart. Is this API accurate enough?